# Does SQL Server really require fully qualified object references to match a statement to a cached execution plan

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, recompile

From SQL Server Docs, section [Execution Plan Caching and Reuse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms181055%28v%3Dsql.100%29):

> The algorithms to match new SQL statements to existing, unused execution plans in the cache require that all object references be fully qualified. For example, the first of these SELECT statements is not matched with an existing plan, and the second is matched:
>
> SELECT * FROM Contact
>
> SELECT * FROM Person.Contact

Is the above statement also true for object references that use the default `dbo`? The reason I ask is because I personally never fully qualify object references (and I assume most people don't) even when using a driver like `JDBC`. Does this mean that all of my `SQL` statements are being re-compiled every time they're executed?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857057/how-does-fqns-affect-query-execution-plan-caching (Would comment if I could)

Comment: This may also help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18769/schema-qualification-necessary-for-query-plan-reuse.

Comment: There are multiple things that can go wrong when you don’t specify the prefix. No, recompilation every time is not a side effect I would ever expect, but you will be storing multiple identical plans for users with different default schemas. What do you gain by *not* typing `dbo.`? Does saving four characters make you more productive? [Please read this popular blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix). TL;DR: I strongly recommend always specifying the schema mostly because leaving it out can cause issues, and because there's no good reason not to.